# Vaadin Theme changes

Tags: css, vaadin

I have custom theme for my VAADIN application in /kopiMapReportGeneration/WebContent/VAADIN/themes i want to change progress idicator in style.css :

```
.v-loading-indicator, .v-loading-indicator-delay, .v-loading-indicator-wait {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   background-position: 50%;
   background-image: url("../customThemes/img/progress.gif");
   background-color: gray;
   opacity: .8;
   -ms-filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   background-attachment: fixed; 
}
```

Here's the image path `/WebContent/VAADIN/themes/customThemes/img/progress.gif`
The problem is that the css changes is not taken into consideration.

Comment: have you set your theme with setTheme("customThemes"); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some points:

1. `style.css` is cached so after any change to your css you should clear your browser cache to get fresh `style.css` resource.
2. your application and main window should have `setTheme("customThemes");`
3. `background-image: url("img/progress.gif");` is sufficient, but `background-image: url("../customThemes/img/progress.gif");` should work too.

Fixing:

1. via Inspect element searach your html page for `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/context-if-any/VAADIN/themes/customThemes/styles.css">` in `HEAD` element. It should be there.
2. visit the css resource and make sure it is up to date and it is not cached
3. make sure that your `/context-if-any/VAADIN/themes/customThemes/img/progress.gif` resource is accessible via web browser

**Conlusion:**

If fixing 1 have linked other theme. -> experiment with setTheme() method in your appplication

If fixing 2 have cached css resource. Hit ctrl + F5 to hard refresh or clear your browser cache.

If fixing 3 goes wrong, your custom theme is not available. Make sure you are packaging your resources into final war.